# SQL query for sql Lite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to produce a report with 3 columns and they all come from the same table containing "local Store", "ID", "TotalSpend", "Member Card Number".

```
Store       Totalnumofmembers    TotalSpendforall
-----      ------------------    ---------------
Store A       1500                   $100.50
Store B       2000                   $500.00
Store C       400                    $300.00
```

And its not giving me the result i wanted when trying to run this query:

```
SELECT "Local Store",
    (SELECT count(ID) FROM ListMembers WHERE Id=a.Id and "Member Card Number" is not null) AS totalnumofmembers,
    (SELECT sum("total spend") FROM ListMembers WHERE Id=a.Id) AS totalspendforall FROM ListMembers a
GROUP BY "Local Store"
```

Is there other method apart from using self join?
thank you

Comment: Can you post what does your query return and what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in one query, you can use a `CASE` statement to do the conditional counting of members with valid card numbers in the same query as summing the total spend.

```
SELECT `Local Store`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `Member Card Number` IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalnumofmembers,
    SUM(`total spend`) AS totalspendforall
FROM ListMembers
GROUP BY `Local Store`
```

If you don't mind having a subquery, then you can try the following

```
SELECT t1.`Local Store`, t1.totalnumofmembers, t2.totalspendforall
FROM
(
    SELECT `Local Store`, COUNT(*) AS totalnumofmembers
    FROM ListMembers
    WHERE `Member Card Number` IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY `Local Store`
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `Local Store`, SUM(`total spend`) AS totalspendforall
    FROM ListMembers
    GROUP BY `Local Store`
) t2
    ON t1.`Local Store` = t2.`Local Store`
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast respond. I tried with another different join.             select a."Local Store",
       count(a.Id) as "Number of Members", sum(b."total spend")
  from ListMembers a
  join ListMembers b on b.id = a.id
where a."Member Card Number" is not null
group by a."Local Store"    i tried with the above and i think it is doing what it is as the numbers were big is hard to tell. is the logic correct? sorry how can i put a break in my comment as each time i press enter to go to next line the msg is posted:(

Comment: ... and ... do you still have a problem?  Would you like to post the query you tried?

Comment: just another question i would like to now add another column which show member sign up who is later than 1st of June. This is different from m y other total member column because the total number column would include all members since inception. My new column should only be those who sign up 1st of june onwards. i tried with the following query and the results of my new column is wrong?

Comment: select a."Local Store",
       count(a.Id) as "Number of Members", 
       sum(b."total spend"),
     (select  count(id) from ListMembers where createdDate >= "01/05/2016" and id=a.id group by "Local Store" ) as "New Sign Up"
  from ListMembers a
  join ListMembers b on b.id = a.id
where a."Member Card Number" is not null
group by a."Local Store"

Answer (score 0):

Thanx. managed to solve it. Didn't realize SQL lite does not use to_date function like oracle. All good. Thank you so much, all.